# Printers quotes in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, quotation

I have had trouble getting the good-looking "curly" quotes in my Malayalam documents using Rachana font and compiled with XeLaTeX. So, when I read TeXbook, I thought I should try using `\lq` and `\rq` directly to see if they give those handsome quotes, but they failed. I was wondering if it is because it is not a TeX primitive or if there was some other problem. What I do now is a round about way, by defining opening quote and closing quote separately and using those macros in the document. It does work, but is certainly not elegant.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: it is impossible to tell from your question, what markup you used, or what output you got so it is very hard to help. Either `\`\`word''` or `“word”` should work, to typeset as “word”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rachana font does not have single or double quotes.

You can ask the font designer to add them.

Alternatively, as a workaround, you can print them by using another font.

Here is a version using macros. You may name the macros as you like. Here I just used `mql`, `mqr`, `mqql` and `mqqr`. You may even name them with Malayalam letters, if you want. The quotes come from the Noto Serif Malayalam font, as an example. Any suitable font can be used.

[image: Rachana quotes]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Rachana}
\newfontface\fontnsm{Noto Serif Malayalam}
\newcommand\mql{{\fontnsm ‘}}
\newcommand\mqr{{\fontnsm ’}}
\newcommand\mqql{{\fontnsm “}}
\newcommand\mqqr{{\fontnsm ”}}
\newfontface\englishfont{Noto Serif}
\newcommand\ഥ{{\fontnsm “}}
\newcommand\ത{{\fontnsm ”}}
\begin{document}
൧൨൩൪൫

” {$\leftarrow$ \englishfont\small This is right double-quote in Rachana font.}

\mql ൧൨൩൪൫\mqr {$\leftarrow$ \englishfont\small Quotes from a different font.}

\mqql ൧൨൩൪൫\mqqr {$\leftarrow$ \englishfont\small Double-quotes.}

\ഥ ൧൨൩൪൫\ത

\end{document}
```